# asp-for in ASP NET Core send checkbox value and false even if checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, tag-helpers

I have a simple .cshtml page:

```
<form asp-controller="SomeController" asp-action="SomeAction">
    @for(int i = 0; i < info.Length; i++)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" value="@info[i].Name" asp-for="Accepted[i]" checked /> <strong>@info[i].Name</strong>
        <br />
    }

    <button type="submit">Some button</button>
</form>
```

And when I submit this form I would like to have FormData like it:

```
info[0]: some-data

info[1]: another-data
```

And I have it in my FormData, but some useless data is added to my FormData that looks like it:

```
info[0]: false

info[1]: false
```

What's more, its setted to false even if checkboxes are checked (when checkboxes are unchecked, they aren't contained in FormData and this useless data also isn't contained).

Why is this happening? Can I remove it while I want to use tag helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, You use index to bind value in `Accepted`, So even you don't bind any value in this index, It will also show default value. You can change type to `string[]` and use `name='Accepted'` to bind value directly.

```
public class ListModel
    {
        public List<string> info { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public string[] Accepted { get; set; }
    }


<form method="post">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.info.Count; i++)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.info[i]" name="Accepted" checked /> <strong>@Model.info[i]</strong>
        <br />
    }  
    <button type="submit">Some button</button>
</form>
```

[image]

Here you can see it will not bind false value.

Comment: I know I can use name, but is it also possible using asp-for?

Comment: asp-for can't be used in list<T> or array directly, It needs index, In your case, If you don't wanna bind null value, you can't use index, So i don't think  you can use asp-for here. Actually asp-for will also generate `name` and `id` in html, If asp-for can't fit your requirement, you don't need to use it.